# requests ajax json ошибка

Tags: python, requests

Здравствуйте пишу парсер, и хочу получить отзывы. 
Нашел Ajax запрос:

```
headers = {
            'Host': 'like.doctor',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Referer': 'https://like.doctor/sankt-peterburg/kliniki/stomatologiya',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cookie': '__cfduid=d01dd1125c1868e9fb31064316ebca6611551725500; _ym_uid=1552415289968903118; _ym_d=1552415289; _ga=GA1.2.515682993.1552415289; _fbp=fb.1.1552415288794.1260102438; PHPSESSID=eqcrsm9bedpmuhh8umvh609jr7; _csrf=4882f54cd0a41e2c6e648b141daab848ae5f43d210d6682d28f5fe677f22a8e6a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22k4k8GzeyreESj8joaeWVu1bDAK7Su_cD%22%3B%7D; _ym_visorc_48769385=w; _ym_isad=2; _gid=GA1.2.1658319103.1552595455; _gat_gtag_UA_118564471_1=1',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'TE': 'Trailers',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

        url_test = "https://like.doctor/service/more-posts"
        proxy = ph.get_proxy_http()
        data_post ={
            'nextpage':'1',
            'perpage':'10',
            'data[city_id]':'false',
            'data[type]':'1',
            'data[user_id]':'false',
            'data[doctor_id]':'false',
            'data[lector_id]':'false',
            'data[event_id]':'false',
            'data[education_id] ':'false',
            'data[service_id]':'false',
            'data[speciality_id]':'false',
            'data[clinic_id][]':'6724',
            'data[include_clinic_info]':'6724',
            'data[temp]':'0',
            'data[show] ':'1',
            'data[additional_data][no_clinic_name]':'true'
        }
        json = requests.post(url_test, data=data_post, headers=headers, proxies=proxy[0], auth=proxy[1]).json()
```

В качестве ответа должен прийти json, но кидает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Project/Parsers_site/like_doctor.py", line 146, in <module>
    like_doctor_ru(7241)
  File "D:/Project/Parsers_site/like_doctor.py", line 68, in like_doctor_ru
    json = requests.post(url_test, data=data_post, headers=headers, proxies=proxy[0], auth=proxy[1]).json()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Я хотел посмотреть что же в ответе пришло, если Json не можем разобраться

Воспользовался вместо json() -> text вывело:

```
���� ��s�[ת�#���<�Wf��    t�  |?���ev��F ��6��u���M��QIGbփd3��C�t�3+AE��W�N��u]v�g�{y��`�nO��
8�U�?X�9�ó|������#�\�H��e[�����fQ��H��4�G�0�=����9�L���<~������0,��6��0��s�r���$%����o��!#\���Pq�&���I�{��}�7az?=�= Zth ��*¬t�jٮ�14k���%����T�Ъ��%���$ʃ�(�|}H t
�|�M��K�9|��=�{����%H@4a�:p�˵E� 6iT0S�|3
```

Также воспользовался content вместо text:

```
b'\x83.\x02\x00\xc4\x925Sv3\xba\xc8\xbe\xb6z\x8f\xa0\xc8\x8a\xe0)\xfe\xf3B#\x08\xbd\xe7\xff\xff\xdc\xa6\xa1,\xc4\xb8\xfb\xd2\x14\xb7\x04?!"\x8d\xaa\x9e8\x848r\xc1\xdc\x1a\x12=\x84\x1e>D\xdb6o\x1a\xc4\x15\xe5[\xa2\....
```

Как можно поправить кодировку, или разобраться с ошибкой разбора json у requests.

[Ссылка на источник](https://like.doctor/sankt-peterburg/kliniki/stomatologiya-noviy-vek-na-prosvescheniya) (блок отзывы)

Comment: Accept-Encoding уберите

Comment: И вообще не нужно пихать заголовки, назначение которых не понимаете

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, я просто скопировал все, что отправляет браузер при запросе